# JPA merge is not happening properly

Tags: eclipselink, vaadin, jpacontainer

```
//parent class    
@OneToMany(mappedBy="parentClass",cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.REMOV    CascadeType.REFRESH}, orphanRemoval =false, fetch = FetchType.EAGE    

@CascadeOnDelete
private List<ChildClass> childClass;

//child class

@ManyToOne(cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.REMOVE,CascadeType.REFRESH})


private ParentClass parentClass;
```

I am facing  some problem in merging.

Sometimes it is working perfectly some time it's not working. 
For example the first time, I am setting

```
amount=30 balamount=20 adjamount=10
```

It is perfectly set.
After that I have set

```
amount=10 balamount=10 adjamount=0
```

but in database I get

```
amount=30 balamount=30 adjamount=0
```

The entity is correctly set. But after committing,
the database is not updated correctly.

I am not getting what the problem is.
Can you please point out what is the problem in my code?

Comment: Improved syntax, grammar and presentation.

Comment: `equals()` / `hashcode()` for the mapper-classes are ok?

Comment: You show a ManyToOne and OneToMany mapping but give no clue where and how are the amount, balamount and adjamount fields mapped, how they are being changed and merged.  Note that your ManyToOne does not have a cascade merge setting.  You should also debug your application to figure out where the balamount=30 is coming from, as that isn't something JPA would just do.

Comment: thanks for your time and help. In debug also values are setting correctly but in sql  queries its setting wrong data. The problem got rectified, I was updating so many entity in single commit. Now I have changed the order of merging and its working fine.